# IE 10+ unable to parse the date strings produced with its own Date.prototype.toLocaleString

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, date

I'm testing an AngularJS application using Selenium. At some point during the test I want to make sure that a date is within an acceptable range. When the test runs, something equivalent to this happens:

```
Date.parse(new Date().toLocaleString())
```

I say "equivalent" because I'm not explicitly calling `toLocaleString()` myself but I am parsing the result of `toLocaleString()` indirectly. When I test on Firefox and Chrome, there is no problem whatsoever. The two browsers are able to parse their own date strings.

On IE, however, I always get `NaN`. I found if I look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760%28v=vs.94%29.aspx#OtherDateFormats) and use a string literal in the same format as what `toLocaleString()` produces, there's no error. For instance, this works:

```
Date.parse("6/9/2010 3:20 pm")
```

I don't understand why when I type in a literal, it works but when I try to use `parse()` on the result of `toLocaleString()` it fails.

I got that error in IE 10 and IE 11 but not in IE 9.

I'm well aware of the issues regarding using `toLocaleString()`, how it can vary depending on user preferences, etc. *In the context of my tests*, using `toLocaleString()` is quite correct.

Comment: Worth noting that ECMA-262 specifically allows implementations an exemption to correctly parse the output of *toLocaleString*. I.e. `Date.parse(new Date().toLocaleString())` may produce *NaN* or incorrect value (in Safari and Firefox it produces *NaN*). So you should not expect "correct" results in any implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Solution

Remove the left-to-right marks that IE puts in the output of `toLocaleString()`:

```
Date.parse(new Date().toLocaleString().replace(/\u200E/g, ''));
```

#### Explanation

The problem is that IE's implementation of `toLocaleString()` outputs [left-to-right marks](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm). Let's take the example with a literal string from the question and see what we get with `toLocaleString()`:

```
new Date(Date.parse("6/9/2010 3:20 pm")).toLocaleString()
> 6/9/2010 03:20:00 PM
```

Let's see what is at the start of the string:

```
new Date(Date.parse("6/9/2010 3:20 pm")).toLocaleString().charCodeAt(0)
> 8206
```

This is a decimal number which corresponds to the hexadecimal `200E`. This is the left-to-right mark which confuses the `parse()` function. There's actually a whole bunch of them before and after each number in the string. If we remove them, then IE is able to parse the string.